# Dropzone.js doesn't upload files on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, file-upload, dropzone.js

I have a dropzone based file uploader. I'll provide the code for it below. Let me first explain the issue:

I'm using an ubuntu machine, my server code, which is node.js and based on the multer library, is also running on an ubuntu machine, front end runs on apache server on a windows machine (I'm saying all these because it might be making a difference, I'm hoping it won't though).

Whenever I upload files on my ubuntu machine, it's smooth sailing. Whenever I upload files on any windows machine, file upload gets completed (progress bar goes from 0 to 100 in a normal way), but the request never reaches the server (at least it never appears on server logs).

The HTML for the dropzone form:

```
<div id="shp" class="uploader">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://serverip:9601/uploadpath"
    method="post"
    class="dropzone"
    id="dropzone">
  </form>
  <button id="submit">Upload</button>
</div>
```

Javascript (Client):

```
Dropzone.options.dropzone = {

  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  acceptedFiles: ".zip",
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  autoProcessQueue: false,

  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
    var dropzone = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      totalProgress = 0;
      dropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    });

  },
  maxFiles : 1,
  parallelUploads: 10000,
  paramName: myParamName,
  uploadMultiple: false
};

function myParamName(){
  return "file";
}
```

Node.js:

```
router.post('/uploadpath', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
    //Do some stuff
    res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: 'Upload Completed!' });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it has nothing to do with dropzone but some other stuff that I haven't posted here. I had some middleware that was validating the mime type of the uploaded file, which is a zip file in my case (I only accept them).

In windows, mime type of a zip file is: application/x-zip-compressed
but in ubuntu, mime type of a zip file is: application/zip

How convenient.

Comment: Mime types for .zip files: application/zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/x-compressed, multipart/x-zip (See https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/)